# kotlin verify input fields

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm moving from Java to Kotlin for my Android development. I want to check if a field in EditText is empty or not. So I've tried to make this:

```
override fun checkFields() {

  val username = username.text.toString().trim().takeUnless { username.text.isNullOrEmpty() } ?: presenter.usernameError()
  val password = password.text.toString().trim().takeUnless { password.text.isNullOrEmpty() } ?: presenter.passwordError()

  presenter.signInWithUsernameAndPassword(username as String,password as String)
}
```

but there are two problems:

1. it passes also to the `signInWithUsernameAndPassword` also if username/password is empty
2. it crashes because gives me this error:

   java.lang.ClassCastException: kotlin.Unit cannot be cast to java.lang.String

why? `takeUnless{}` converts String to Unit?

Thanks

Comment: Could you add more information? The `presenter.usernameError()` method might be of interest as well. Also you're redefining `username` and `password` which doesn't seem right.

Comment: Did you mean to throw the return values from `preseneter.usernameError()` and `presenter.passwordError()`? If so, you need to change your statements after `?:` to `throw preseneter.usernameError()` and `throw presenter.passwordError()` respectively.

Comment: usernameError() and showError() must be open a dialog alert to show user that field is empty @tynn

Comment: So these return `Unit`?

Comment: @tynn yes..it's probably because the fun() I've inserted in my code returns void...but I want to try if there is a way to do it: if(usernameEditText).isEmpty() and the same with the password show a dialog, elsewhere continue with login, without using when

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first statement in the method is like the following in Java.

```
String username = !username.text.isNullOrEmpty() ? username.text.toString().trim() : presenter.usernameError();
```

This is why you get the `ClassCastException` if `presenter.usernameError()` is a `Unit`-typed (or `void` in Java) function. I think this is not what you want.

Provided that both `presenter.usernameError()` and `presenter.passwordError()` are `Unit`-typed functions, you can

```
val username = username.text.toString().trim().takeUnless { it.isNullOrEmpty() } ?: return presenter.usernameError()
val password = password.text.toString().trim().takeUnless { it.isNullOrEmpty() } ?: return presenter.passwordError()

presenter.signInWithUsernameAndPassword(username as String,password as String)
```

`it` refers to `username.text.toString().trim()` or `password.text.toString().trim()`, which are the instances that called `takeUnless` method.

Comment: there is a way to avoid to call signInWithUsernameAndPassword() if one of two fields are empty?

Comment: It is `return`ing from the function in the code. You see I added `return` after `?:`. Since the type of `checkFields()` is `Unit`, it is safe to return with calling a `Unit`-typed function. It returns before assigning the `Unit` value to the `String` variables, so it does not throw the cast exception.